# How to detect unwanted Firefox add-ons?

Tags: firefox, adware, malware-detection

I have a Firefox add-on that seems to inject ads on the top of the pages when I'm using search engines.

For example, for a search on hard drive on Google.com, I have this banner on top:

```
    You may also be interested in hard drive dock, lacie hard drive, iomega hard drive, best external hard drive.
```

This is somehow related to "superfish.com"

I could easily find which add-on does by uninstalling add-ons, but I would like to have a method to do this.

I'm not saying that this add-on is a malware: I may have agreed to have these ads displayed in my browser, but I would like to find the terms, and even better, read the source code of the relevant part of this add-on.

So, what is the method to do this using built-in Firefox tools, Firefox add-ons, and possibly my OS (Linux in this case) ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox and hit F12 to bring up the developer interface. Select the 'inspect' tab and mouse over the portion of the page you wish to examine. I can't be more specific than this because I don't use the default console. The Firebug add-on for Firefox is best tool for this sort of thing.